# Accessing data found in another object/script

Tags: lua, moonsharp, tabletop-simulator

In Tabletop Simulator, how can I exchange information between objects?

Is there a way, for example, to create a global variable?

Comment: Question was asked to me elsewhere. Posted it here to help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no global variables, and you can't create public object properties. But you're not out of luck.

---

You can get and set an object's property using `.getVar`/`.getTable` and `.setVar`/`.setTable`. [Docs](https://api.tabletopsimulator.com/object/#global-function).

For example,

**Object `aaaaaa`**

```lua
function onChat(message, player)
    local o = getObjectFromGUID("bbbbbb")
    local x = o.getVar("x")
    x = x + 1
    o.setVar("x", x)
    print(x)
end
```

**Object `bbbbbb`**

```lua
x = 0
```

You can also use `Global.getVar(...)`, etc.

---

Alternatively, you can create a method, and call using [`.call`](https://api.tabletopsimulator.com/object/#call). This provides better encapsulation.

For example,

**Object `aaaaaa`**

```lua
function onChat(message, player)
    local o = getObjectFromGUID("82fbcf")
    local x = o.call("getX")
    x = x + 1
    o.call("setX", { value = x })
    print(x)
end
```

**Object `bbbbbb`**

```lua
x = 0

function getX(args)
    return x
end

function setX(args)
    x = args["value"]
end
```

The argument can only be a table.

You can also use `Global.call(...)`.